# RWD and smartphone's screen x browser window size

Tags: css, responsive-design, smartphone, screen-size

I'm developing a site with Responsive Web Design (RWD). I decided to use 640 pixels as the breakpoint between mobile and desktop, as [this site](http://samuelcrane.com/) appears to do (as can be seen when resizing the browser on PC). However, when using [this site](https://browsersize.com/) to measure the screen in my smartphone, I get the following properties:

```
Browser window size: 980 x 1392
Screen size: 360 x 640
```

Somehow the browser window gets much bigger than the screen, and the website appears as if on a desktop. It seems I need `Browser window size` to be about the same as `Screen size`, so that the "small version" of the site appear on the smartphone. How do I achieve that?

EDIT

After I added

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```

to the code, the page appeared correctly in the smartphone's browser. However, I still don't understand why [`browsersize.com`](https://browsersize.com/) returns a browser window size so larger than the screen size.

Comment: Your requirement is to clear. Don't confuse btw the Browser window size and screen window size. Screen window size will constant when you resize and Browser window will change on resize.

Comment: @AravindS I cannot even resize the browser window in my smartphone. I don't think you understood my point.

Comment: Maybe this article explains the strange default behavior of the mobile browsers: https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing website and you want it to be RWD, you should cover the most of screen like desktops, tablets and mobiles, so the [bootstrap media queries](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) can be a good choose for your website, but if you decided to use 640 pixels as the breakpoint between mobile and desktop! then what about other screen size, you probably need some thing like following code to cover most of screens.

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

But if you looking for specific screen size you can use this [link](https://github.com/alireza-nazari/responsive-media-queries) and select what you need from that file.

The [browsersize](https://browsersize.com) is tools for testing your web pages with specific size like [chrome inspect element responsive](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports) tools.

But the `viewport` is quick fix for your problem.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```

A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser. [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the difference between window.innerWidth and screen.width.

- window.innerWidth gives physical pixels of the window (the inner width of the window or more accurately viewport) which includes scrollbars
- screen.width gives logical ([CSS pixels](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#css-pixels)) of the screen (not just the browser window)

Also adding viewport meta tag sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device.

This is the function that https://browsersize.com/ uses to show the sizes:

```
function updateSizes() {

    var uniwin = {
        width: window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
            || document.body.offsetWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight
            || document.body.offsetHeight
    };

    $("info_sw").innerHTML = screen.width;
    $("info_sh").innerHTML = screen.height;
    $("info_ww").innerHTML = uniwin.width;
    $("info_wh").innerHTML = uniwin.height;
}
```